# Memory error JVM starting minecraft server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jvm, minecraft, digital-ocean

## I'm trying to put a minecraft server into my digital ocean ubuntu server

I followed all the steps in a tutorial by digital ocean and when I get to this part:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

I get the following error message:

```
OpenJDK Client VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x63d50000, 715849728, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/avi/minecraft/hs_err_pid1418.log
```

and the following log file:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2827), pid=1421, tid=3063196480
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_101) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (24.95-b01 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0xb6707400):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=1422, stack(0xb68fa000,0xb694b000)]

Stack: [0xb68fa000,0xb694b000]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0xb6707400 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=1422, stack(0xb68fa000,0xb694b000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 146580     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 146580     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 fd:01 146580     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
09da7000-09dc8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
4e800000-63d50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
8e800000-94600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b4454000-b44ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b44ff000-b467f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b467f000-b4681000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b4681000-b4700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b4700000-b4728000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
b4728000-b6721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6721000-b6800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b686c000-b6874000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 146607     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b6874000-b6875000 r--p 00007000 fd:01 146607     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b6875000-b6876000 rw-p 00008000 fd:01 146607     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b6876000-b6880000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917692     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b6880000-b6881000 r--p 00009000 fd:01 917692     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b6881000-b6882000 rw-p 0000a000 fd:01 917692     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b6882000-b688c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917666     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b688c000-b688d000 r--p 00009000 fd:01 917666     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b688d000-b688e000 rw-p 0000a000 fd:01 917666     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b688e000-b68a3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917642     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b68a3000-b68a4000 r--p 00015000 fd:01 917642     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b68a4000-b68a5000 rw-p 00016000 fd:01 917642     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b68a5000-b68a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b68a7000-b68ae000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917597     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b68ae000-b68af000 r--p 00006000 fd:01 917597     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b68af000-b68b0000 rw-p 00007000 fd:01 917597     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b68b0000-b68b8000 rw-s 00000000 fd:01 1179680    /tmp/hsperfdata_avi/1421
b68b8000-b68df000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 146592     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b68df000-b68e0000 r--p 00026000 fd:01 146592     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b68e0000-b68e1000 rw-p 00027000 fd:01 146592     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b68e1000-b68ef000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 146593     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b68ef000-b68f0000 r--p 0000d000 fd:01 146593     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b68f0000-b68f1000 rw-p 0000e000 fd:01 146593     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b68f1000-b68f8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917674     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
b68f8000-b68f9000 r--p 00006000 fd:01 917674     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
b68f9000-b68fa000 rw-p 00007000 fd:01 917674     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
b68fa000-b68fd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b68fd000-b694b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:1422]
b694b000-b6967000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917528     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b6967000-b6968000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:01 917528     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b6968000-b69ac000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917515     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
b69ac000-b69ad000 r--p 00043000 fd:01 917515     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
b69ad000-b69ae000 rw-p 00044000 fd:01 917515     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
b69ae000-b6a8a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 131185     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
b6a8a000-b6a8e000 r--p 000dc000 fd:01 131185     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
b6a8e000-b6a8f000 rw-p 000e0000 fd:01 131185     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
b6a8f000-b6a96000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6a96000-b70c7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 146614     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
b70c7000-b70dd000 r--p 00630000 fd:01 146614     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
b70dd000-b70ec000 rw-p 00646000 fd:01 146614     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
b70ec000-b7508000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7508000-b7520000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917645     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
b7520000-b7521000 r--p 00017000 fd:01 917645     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
b7508000-b7520000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917645     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
b7520000-b7521000 r--p 00017000 fd:01 917645     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
b7521000-b7522000 rw-p 00018000 fd:01 917645     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
b7522000-b753a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917643     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
b753a000-b753b000 r--p 00018000 fd:01 917643     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
b753b000-b753c000 rw-p 00019000 fd:01 917643     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
b753c000-b753e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b753e000-b7541000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917535     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b7541000-b7542000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 917535     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b7542000-b7543000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 917535     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b7543000-b76eb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917676     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76eb000-b76ec000 ---p 001a8000 fd:01 917676     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76ec000-b76ee000 r--p 001a8000 fd:01 917676     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76ee000-b76ef000 rw-p 001aa000 fd:01 917676     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76ef000-b76f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76f8000-b76f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76f9000-b76fa000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
b76fa000-b7706000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 146625     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7706000-b7707000 r--p 0000c000 fd:01 146625     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7707000-b7708000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:01 146625     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7708000-b770b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b770b000-b770c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b770c000-b772c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 917657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b772c000-b772d000 r--p 0001f000 fd:01 917657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b772d000-b772e000 rw-p 00020000 fd:01 917657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
bf9cc000-bf9cd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
bf9ff000-bfa20000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
java_command: minecraft_server.jar nogui
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x4eb390], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x4eb390], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x3c91d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x3c91d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x3c91d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x3c91d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x3c9060], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTRAP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)
uname:Linux 3.13.0-88-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 21:10:37 UTC 2016 i686
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19
                                         uname:Linux 3.13.0-88-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 21:10:37 UTC 2016 i686
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 3810, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:0.00 0.01 0.02

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:         507200 kB
MemFree:          415836 kB
Buffers:            3024 kB
Cached:            26864 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            47656 kB
Inactive:          23620 kB
Active(anon):      41424 kB
Inactive(anon):     5648 kB
Active(file):       6232 kB
Inactive(file):    17972 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:             0 kB
HighFree:              0 kB
LowTotal:         507200 kB
LowFree:          415836 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                64 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         41424 kB
Mapped:            20960 kB
Shmem:              5648 kB
Slab:              10704 kB
SReclaimable:       5088 kB
SUnreclaim:         5616 kB
KernelStack:         736 kB
PageTables:         1160 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      253600 kB
Committed_AS:     862388 kB
VmallocTotal:     512000 kB
VmallocUsed:        7072 kB
VmallocChunk:     499388 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       26616 kB
DirectMap2M:      497664 kB


CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 63 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, erms, tsc

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 63
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L v3 @ 1.80GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 1799.998
cache size      : 30720 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x$
bogomips        : 3599.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 507200k(415836k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK Client VM (24.95-b01) for linux-x86 JRE (1.7.0_101-b00), built on Apr 24 2016 20:33:21 by "buildd" with gcc 4.8.2

time: Wed Jul 13 01:25:36 2016
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

I know it's a memory allocation issue, but I have no idea how to solve it.
would really appreciate some help on the matter.

P.S. I know I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough memory to start a JVM of that size.

```
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:         507200 kB
MemFree:          415836 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
```

You have about 415 kB free, and no swap space so this is a hard limit.  I suggest you add some swap space, at least 512 MB, AND limit your heap size to about 300 MB so there is room for the JVM to run as well.  Note: this might be too small for the server in which case you need more memory.

Answer (score 1):

The -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M flag tries to allocate 1 Gb of memory.

Since its a digital ocean droplet maybe your server doesnt have 1 Gb of Ram.